# Sorting an array of values by shifting to the right

Tags: c++, arrays, function, sorting

I have to make a method that sorts an array of values going from lowest value to the highest. The way these  functions are supposed to work is that it grabs each value, tries to put them in rising order going from left to right by shifting every bigger value to the right.

I have made the following functions:

```
int findIndex(double *arr, double num, int length)
{

   for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
   {
      if (arr[i] > num)
         return i;
     }
   return length - 1;
}

void placeOnIndex(double *arr, double num,int index, int length)
{

   if (length > 1 && arr[index] != num) 
   {
       for (int i = length - 1; i > 0; i--)
       {
            arr[i] = arr[i - 1];
       }

       arr[index] = num;
   }
}

void insertSort(double* arr, int length)
{
   for (int ix = 0; ix < length; ix++)
   {
       double num = arr[ix]; //Current value to put as far to the left as possible
       int index = findIndex(arr, num, ix+1);  //Locates index to put it
       placeOnIndex(arr, num, index, ix+1); //Uses the index to put in the right place
   }

}

void main()
{
   double arr[4] = {1,8,4,5};
   insertSort((arr), 4);
}
```

My problem is that the output with this array becomes:
   1,1,5,8

Apparently it sometimes overrides the second element in my array. Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. If the array is longer even more values are overridden.

I'm sorry if it looks confusing, english isn't my native tongue.

Comment: In `placeOnIndex` when `i == index` you place `num` in `arr[index]`. But what happens to the value that was stored in `arr[index]` beforehand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
for (int i = length - 1; i > 0; i--)
```

causes all the elements to move right, not just the ones that should move.

You need

```
for (int i = length - 1; i > index; i--)
```